# Which other SE sites are our natural affinities?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[This answer](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/952/83) rightly points out that part of what makes SE work is the multi-site aspect: experienced users on one SE site will naturally start looking at others too, and instead of 130 isolated communities you end up with more cross-fertilization.

When this site launched, as Moderators, we tried to reach moderators of other SE sites.  But that's too narrow, and we're now Community Building instead.  Where else on the SE network should we be looking for users who might also be interested in this site?  Which sites' topics are somehow related to our topics?

If we can identify relevant sites, we might be able to propose some cross-site ads.

Comment: Maybe CogSci?  I don't know the field or the site well enough to say, hence this comment instead of a post.

Comment: Just a hunch: Arqade might have some people who are avid gamers and also host game servers. That one sticks out to me a lot, although I don't know how many Arqade users fall into this category.

Comment: Related: http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/221/83

Comment: I agree.   I like cb.se and I visit it every day, but it still feels like it's not getting enough traction

Answer (score 9):

Workplace may be the most obvious one.  World Building might have some interest possibly.  Certainly any guild/clan leaders or server admins on Arqade, but that's a minority of the gaming community.  Actually, Game Design might have some natural affinity as well as a lot of games need to form a culture and community around them.

Additional very minor ones could include things like Sec.SE (need community buy in for security to be effective)

I think the real key comes down to how involved communities are in the day to day of a particular field.  If the topic area regularly deals with group management issues, then we may be of interest.

Comment: Huh, Workplace -- I wouldn't have thought of that, but that makes sense.

Comment: We would have to make the ad not take any questions away from The Workplace, or else a community ad would never get voted in. It seems like that'd be hard to do.

Comment: My gut feeling is that an ad could be suitably focused to both sites' mutual benefit.  But I don't have a concrete idea yet.

Answer (score 5):

I think [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) projects usually involve a component of community building too.

Same with [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).

Maybe also [Role Playing games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4):

Every meta site on stack exchange has an affinity to community building.

I don't think any specific site has an affinity to community building, but there are tags across a number of sites that do.

A few tags I can think of:

[communities on user experience se](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community)

[dojo on martial arts se](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dojo)

[forum on webmasters se](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum)

[server administration on gaming se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server-administration)

if it's possible to target pages that have questions with specific tags, it would make sense to target the tags above, and others like them.

Comment: Even without the ability to target questions by tags, if a topic is relevant on another site they might be willing to have ads from us. Thanks for pointing these out.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed an Area51 proposal that will have some overlap

- [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61762/gamification) - We have several questions related to adding this type of incentive to a community

Comment: Double thumbs up on Gamification and anything involving "Engagement".  Maybe even the UX.se site...  Community is an important part of the "user experience"